# Trying to pull out entries in a file/or many files* that only contain 7 characters in part of a line within the files'

Tags: grep

I have many files that I am trying to comb thru and pull out the entries that only contain 7 digits.

Here is an example of what I am trying to pull out.

```
    CDR Calling Number: +15555555555
    CDR Called Number: 5557600
```

This is the current command I have to pull this, but this command also pulls other entries I do not want.

```
cat file* |grep -v "CDR Called Number: +1" |grep -B 1 "CDR Called Number"
```

Here are some entries that I have tried without success

```
grep '^.......' file*
grep -E '^.{7}$' file*
sed -rn '/^.{7}$/p' file*
```

Comment: You can limit matches to those that form whole words using `-w` or `--word-regexp`, ex. `grep -Ew '[0-9]{7}'`

Comment: What entries is it matching that you _do not_ want? Please add those to your question so we can see what needs to be excluded from the pattern

Answer (score 1):

You want

```bsh
grep -E '\D\d{7}$'
```

- a non-digit followed by 7 digits and the end of the line.

This would also work

```bsh
awk 'length($NF) == 7 && $NF !~ /[^0-9]/'
```

- last field is 7 characters long and does not contain a non-digit.

---

A couple of the errors in your samples:

- `grep '^.......'` -- the line *starts* with 7 of *any character*
- `grep -E '^.{7}$'` -- line is exactly 7 characters long.